# MAVROS interaction with a gimbal (Pixhawk)

Tags: ros, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to put a gimbal under my quad with a webcam, and a px4flow sensor on it so I know the two cameras are always looking at the ground straight on. How can I get angle information from the gimbal through the Pixhawk using mavros? I am new to MAVROS. Thanks for all the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218035/mavros-interaction-with-a-gimbal-(pixhawk)/) by [mcelhennyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23994/mcelhennyi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that you really need gimball for px4flow. It has it's own IMU. Also i think that px4 firmware can only handle flow sensor pointed straight to ground (horizon base) and with fixed joint to base (airframe).

There no plugin for gimballs, because there no common messages for that.
StormBGC32 can be controlled via mavlink, but i'm do not know does it return orientation status or not.

But because storm uses COMMAND_LONG messages, some control may be done via command plugin.

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1